# How do I remove div's from displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's the menu:

```
<a id="page1" href="" onclick="loadPage('page1')">Home</a>
    <a id="page2" href="" onclick="loadPage('page2')">About us</a>
    <a id="page3" href="" onclick="loadPage('page3')">Services</a>
    <a id="page4" href="" onclick="loadPage('page4')">Partners</a>
    <a id="page5" href="" onclick="loadPage('page5')">Contact us</a>
```

The javascript so far:

```
<script>
    var var1="";
    function loadPage(varcontent){
      var1=varcontent;
      alert(var1);
    }

    </script>
```

Here's the div:

```
<div id="page_1" class=welcome_bye_holder>
      <h1 id="page_1">Welcome to Cyber Technician:</h1>
      <p1 id="page_1">An I.T. Technician and cyber security<br> for the         <br>Southport, North Sefton area.</p1>
    </div>
```

So what i basically need is some javascript that removes divs aswell as the content within them unless page1 == document.GetElemenyById="page_1". The best I could find is var elem = document.getElementById("myDiv");
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem); from what I understand from that is it only removes the content and not the divs, unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Remove them or not display them? You can make them invisible with display:none css property and then display only the one you want. If you remove it you will not be able to recover it easily.

Comment: The css property sounds the best solution, you got the javascript for it?

Answer (score 0):

i changed a bit your html structure. maybe it's easier to understand.

maybe the JQ code could be simplified, but i wrote it in a hurry. here's an examplanation :

each `a` has a `data-target` that corresponds to a `div`  . so, when you click on `a` you check if a `div` has that `id` . that div remains displayed the others are hidden.

i thought of 3 ways to do this.

**Solution A.**  using `hide()` and `show()`

```js
$("a").on("click",function(){
     var tgtID = $(this).attr("data-target")
     $("div").each(function(){
       if(!$(this).is(tgtID)){
       $(this).hide()
       }else{
       $(this).show()
     }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <a data-target="#page_1" href="#">Home</a>
    <a data-target="#page_2" href="#" >About us</a>
    <a data-target="#page_3"  href="#">Services</a>
    <a data-target="#page_4"  href="#">Partners</a>
    <a data-target="#page_5" href="#" >Contact us</a>
    
    <div id="page_1" class=welcome_bye_holder>
      <h1 id="page_1">Welcome to Cyber Technician:</h1>
      <p1 id="page_1">An I.T. Technician and cyber security<br> for the         <br>Southport, North Sefton area.</p1>
    </div>
    <div id="page_2" class=welcome_bye_holder>
      <h1 id="page_2">PAGE 2</h1>
      <p1 id="page_2">I PAGE 2 <br /> I PAGE 2</p1>
    </div>
```

**Solution B** another solution would be to use `addClass()` and `removeClass()` to toggle the class `hideme` which in css you set to hide the div `.hideme { display:none;}` . see snippet below

```js
$("a").on("click",function(){
     var tgtID = $(this).attr("data-target")
     $("div").each(function(){
       if(!$(this).is(tgtID)){
       $(this).addClass("hideme")
     } else {
      $(this).removeClass("hideme")
     }
      
   
  })
    })
```

```css
.hideme {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <a data-target="#page_1" href="#">Home</a>
    <a data-target="#page_2" href="#" >About us</a>
    <a data-target="#page_3"  href="#">Services</a>
    <a data-target="#page_4"  href="#">Partners</a>
    <a data-target="#page_5" href="#" >Contact us</a>
    
    <div id="page_1" class=welcome_bye_holder>
      <h1 id="page_1">Welcome to Cyber Technician:</h1>
      <p1 id="page_1">An I.T. Technician and cyber security<br> for the         <br>Southport, North Sefton area.</p1>
    </div>
    <div id="page_2" class=welcome_bye_holder>
      <h1 id="page_2">PAGE 2</h1>
      <p1 id="page_2">I PAGE 2 <br /> I PAGE 2</p1>
    </div>
```

**Solution C** using `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` , it works smoother and nicer. maybe you prefer it like so.

see snippet below

```js
$("a").on("click",function(){
     var tgtID = $(this).attr("data-target")
     $("div").each(function(){
       if(!$(this).is(tgtID)){
         $(this).slideUp()
       }else{
         $(this).slideDown()
      
     }
  })
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <a data-target="#page_1" href="#">Home</a>
    <a data-target="#page_2" href="#" >About us</a>
    <a data-target="#page_3"  href="#">Services</a>
    <a data-target="#page_4"  href="#">Partners</a>
    <a data-target="#page_5" href="#" >Contact us</a>
    
    <div id="page_1" class=welcome_bye_holder>
      <h1 id="page_1">Welcome to Cyber Technician:</h1>
      <p1 id="page_1">An I.T. Technician and cyber security<br> for the         <br>Southport, North Sefton area.</p1>
    </div>
    <div id="page_2" class=welcome_bye_holder>
      <h1 id="page_2">PAGE 2</h1>
      <p1 id="page_2">I PAGE 2 <br /> I PAGE 2</p1>
    </div>
  <div id="page_3" class=welcome_bye_holder>
     <h1 id="page_3">PAGE 3</h1>
      <p1 id="page_3">I PAGE 3 <br /> I PAGE 3</p1>
    </div>
    <div id="page_4" class=welcome_bye_holder>
      <h1 id="page_4">PAGE 4</h1>
      <p1 id="page_4">I PAGE 4 <br /> I PAGE 4</p1>
    </div>
<div id="page_5" class=welcome_bye_holder>
      <h1 id="page_5">PAGE 5</h1>
      <p1 id="page_5">I PAGE 5 <br /> I PAGE 5</p1>
    </div>
```

**Solution C.1** if you want all the divs to be hidden at page load, and only show one div after you click on an `a` , use this

```js
$('div').hide()
$("a").on("click",function(){
     var tgtID = $(this).attr("data-target")
     $("div").each(function(){
       if($(this).is(tgtID)){
  $(this).slideDown()
       }else{
         $(this).slideUp()
         }
  })
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <a data-target="#page_1" href="#">Home</a>
    <a data-target="#page_2" href="#" >About us</a>
    <a data-target="#page_3"  href="#">Services</a>
    <a data-target="#page_4"  href="#">Partners</a>
    <a data-target="#page_5" href="#" >Contact us</a>
    
    <div id="page_1" class=welcome_bye_holder>
      <h1 id="page_1">Welcome to Cyber Technician:</h1>
      <p1 id="page_1">An I.T. Technician and cyber security<br> for the         <br>Southport, North Sefton area.</p1>
    </div>
    <div id="page_2" class=welcome_bye_holder>
      <h1 id="page_2">PAGE 2</h1>
      <p1 id="page_2">I PAGE 2 <br /> I PAGE 2</p1>
    </div>
  <div id="page_3" class=welcome_bye_holder>
     <h1 id="page_3">PAGE 3</h1>
      <p1 id="page_3">I PAGE 3 <br /> I PAGE 3</p1>
    </div>
    <div id="page_4" class=welcome_bye_holder>
      <h1 id="page_4">PAGE 4</h1>
      <p1 id="page_4">I PAGE 4 <br /> I PAGE 4</p1>
    </div>
<div id="page_5" class=welcome_bye_holder>
      <h1 id="page_5">PAGE 5</h1>
      <p1 id="page_5">I PAGE 5 <br /> I PAGE 5</p1>
    </div>
```

let me know if one of this 3 solutions work for you

Comment: You should not give multiple elements the same ID. It might be better to work with a data attribute or a class in this case.

Comment: changed the solution. see now if it works. i've put `data-target` on `a` instead of `id`

Comment: added 2 more solutions. one of the 3 must work for you :) let me know

Comment: edited them again :) saw a little error. check Solution C it should work. ////// if i understood right, you want when you click on home, all the divs to hide except the one with `#page_1` , the same for About us, all divs hide except `#page_2` and so on , right ? solution C works. i added all 5 divs

Comment: what exactly doesn;t work ? in the snippets is working as you want and it doesn't work in your own project ? be more specific please :)

Comment: Well nothing disappears, it stays the same.

Comment: do you have Jquery library added ? did you change your HTML code as it is in my Examples ? because as you can see, in the snippets, the divs disappear

Comment: no. you need to add jQuery to your project in the `<head>` section 

add this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I'll try again :D

Comment: Now my web server is displaying a blank screen.

Comment: Ok i've moved all JS to the head tags, done everything you asked, i can see it all and still nothing!

Comment: Inspect element in your browser...and look in the console. Is there any error there ? Copy and paste it here

Answer (score 0):

I still didn't understand from your title if you want to remove the specific element or to set his display to none. I did both cases in an example below.

P.S: I modified your HTML code. Is not good to attribue two same id's ...

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("page_0");

function myfunction(){
  
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem); 
}

function yourfunction(){

elem.style.display = "none"; 
}
```

```html
<div id="page_A" class="welcome_bye_holder">
      <h1 id="h1_page_A">Plain, simple title: </h1>
      <p id="p_sub_page_A"> Plain, simple, not importan text.</p>
    </div>
<div id="page_0" class="welcome_bye_holder">
      <h1 id="page_1">Welcome to Cyber Technician:</h1>
      <p id="page_2">An I.T. Technician and cyber security<br> for the         <br>Southport, North Sefton area.</p>
    </div>
<div id="page_X" class="welcome_bye_holder">
      <h1 id="h1_page_X">SOME H1 title:</h1>
      <p id="p_page_X"> some random text,nothing important.</p>
    </div>
<button onclick="myfunction()">remove me!</button>
<button onclick="yourfunction()">hide me!</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use css for hide it,

```
<div style="display:none">
<h1> Show/Hide content here
</div>
```

Then use JavaScript to show it. 
Refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)